# Are double pendulums eventually periodic?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, classical-mechanics, chaos-theory

I've often heard it said that the motion of a double pendulum is non-periodic.  (This may be related to the fact that it's a chaotic system, but I'm not sure about that.) But this does not seem possible to me, for the following reason. Let $\theta_1$ and $\theta_2$ be the angles of the two masses relative to the vertical. Then we can consider the two-dimensional phase space with a $\theta_1$ axis and a $\theta_2$ axis, and the motion of the double pendulum is a continuous curve $\gamma:[0,\infty) \rightarrow [0,2\pi]\times[0,2\pi]$.  The thing is, I'm pretty sure such a curve must be self-intersecting. Because if it's not self-intersecting, then its graph would cover more and more of the codomain with time, and so I think you'd get a space-filling curve.  And yet space-filling curves are always self-intersecting, so you'd get a contradiction. Thus $\gamma$ must be self-intersecting, and thus the motion of a double pendulum is always periodic.

So what's wrong with my reasoning? Or is my reasoning correct, and is the motion of a double pendulum always periodic, just with such a long period that it looks non-periodic? If so, is there a formula for the period?

Comment: I guess one could consider a chaotic system to have an infinitely long period...

Comment: @JonCuster Well, if my reasoning is correct then the period must be finite.

Comment: Why are there a finite number of points in your phase space?

Comment: @JonCuster There aren't a finite number of points.  Certainly the cardinality of $[0,2\pi]\times[0,2\pi]$ is infinite. I'm just saying that $\gamma$ must be self-intersecting, and if it is self-intersecting then due to conservation of energy it must be a closed curve, so the motion of the double pendulum must be periodic with finite period.

Comment: $\gamma(t)=(t^{-1},\cos(t))$ is an example of a continuous non self-intersecting curve, so you know your reasoning is false and you're missing some assumptions!

Comment: @NeuroFuzzy I didn't mean to suggest that you can't have a continuous non-self-intersecting curve, but that you can't have one where the range is bounded (and the domain is unbounded).

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan my curve is nonintersecting and maps from $[1,\infty]$ into $[0,1]\times [-1,1]$.

Comment: The answers have already explained several things wrong with the premise, but it seems important to point out that your notion of a space-filling curve is not correct. For instance, on a torus $T^2 = \mathbb R^2 / (2 \pi \mathbb Z)^2$ (the space on which $\theta_1$ and $\theta_2$ live), a line of irrational slope is a curve $\mathbb R \rightarrow T^2$ which has dense image, but is not space-filling (in fact its image is measure 0). While it does approximately recur infinitely often (as in the Poincare recurrence theorem), it is an injection.

Comment: @LoganM Interesting, I wasn't aware a continuous curve could be dense and non-self-intersecting  but still have measure zero.  In any case, do you know if the trajectory of a double pendulum is an instance of this phenomenon?

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan My naive expectation is that a "generic" double pendulum trajectory (in position space, not in phase space) is self-intersecting, but I do not know any proof of this. I do know that the trajectory is never space-filling, which actually follows just from the fact that the curve is differentiable. Also, as eranreches' answer explains, the dynamics of the system are determined not solely by $\theta_1,\theta_2$, but also their conjugate momenta, so even if a trajectory is self-intersecting it is not necessarily periodic (and in fact is rarely periodic).

Comment: To elaborate on the points above:  the usual proof that a space-filling curve is self-intersecting is that $[0,1]$ is compact, $[0,1] \times [0,1]$ is Hausdorff, and any continuous bijective map from a compact space to a Hausdorff space is a homeomorphism.  Since the two spaces are not homeomorphic and the curve map is surjective, it cannot be injective, and so there must be self-intersection points.  However, this proof doesn't work if you try to map $[0, \infty)$ to the unit square, since $[0, \infty)$ is not compact.

Comment: @MichaelSeifert So does that mean there does exist a non-self-intersecting space-filling curve where the domain of $\gamma$ is $[0,\infty)$? Do you have an example of such a curve?

Comment: When I wrote that last comment, I didn't know the answer to that question.  However, I now think that [this answer on Math.SE](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/43098/248639) could be extended to prove that there is no continuous bijection from $[0, \infty)$ to $[0,1]^2$.  (Consider the images $f|_{[0,n]}$ instead of the images $f|_{[-n,n]}$).

Comment: It's not even true in the limit for infinitesimally small angles. For a suitable choice of lengths of the rods, the relative frequencies of the two modes can be anything - for example $1$ and $\sqrt 2$ Hz.

Comment: One thing you could do is write down the Lagrangian for the system and solve the Euler-Lagrange equation to obtain the equations of motion. You will see that the double-pendulum motion is erratic/chaotic and is generally not periodic.

Comment: I think your phase space is lacking some dimensions.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

**Short answer: No. General trajectories of double pendulum are not periodic**.

You need to distinguish between two aspects: the trajectory in the spatial coordinate system and the trajectory in phase space.

Your claim about $\gamma$ is about the first aspect and is thus false. It is perfectly okay for trajectories to intersect in the real space, and this doesn't mean the solution is periodic.

However, in the phase space it is forbidden for different trajectories to intersect (because of the uniqueness of the solution of ODEs given initial conditions). And if they do, you are correct that the dynamic is periodic. Indeed, notice that it may be that the mass travels through the same spatial point twice, but it can be with different velocities.

As @agemO suggested in a comment below, it is important to stress that although the solution is not periodic, it seem like it is getting close to there (which is probably what confuses you). Suppose for example that the mass starts from a point $(x,y)$ in the XY plane with velocity vector $(v_{x},v_{y})$. Then according to **Poincare Recurrence Theorem**, after some time the mass will travel as close as you want to that point with a very very similar velocity - but they are not guaranteed to be the same. In other words, the motion is as close as you want to be periodic, but it misses, and the resulting behavior is chaotic.

There is another very interesting theorem that should also be worth stating in this case. It is called **Poincare Bendixson Theorem**, and it states that a traped trajectory in 2D phase space must eventually repeat itself (given that the trapping region doesn't contain fixed points). But in this case the phase space is 4D and the theorem doesn't apply.

Comment: "Indeed, notice that it may be that the mass travels through the same spatial point twice, but it can be with different velocities." No, that's not possible, because of conservation of energy.  That's why I say that if $\gamma$ ever returns to the same point, then the motion must be periodic.

Comment: The velocity has both direction and magnitude. The magnitude must be the same, but the direction is not.

Comment: The direction doesn't have any freedom, it has to be tangential to the string.  Once you know the position, that's enough to determine the direction.

Comment: But you have two rods. I think that gives you this freedom.

Comment: It very much does give you that freedom!  For $m_1=m_2=\ell_1=\ell_2=g=1$, we have $E=\dot{\theta}_1^2 + 
 \cos(\theta_1-\theta_2) \dot{\theta}_1\dot{\theta}_2 + 
\frac{1}{2}\dot{\theta}_2^2 + 2 \sin(\theta_1) + \sin(\theta_2)$, which for any given $E,\theta_1,\theta_2$ has a continuum of solutions in $\dot{\theta}_1$ and $\dot{\theta}_2$.

Comment: @eranreches It doesn't give you any freedom.  The direction of the velocity of the first mass is tangential to the first string, and the direction of the velocity of the second mass is tangential to the second string.  And the configurations of the two strings are completely determined by $\theta_1$ and $\theta_2$.

Comment: @NeuroFuzzy What about when you consider conservation of angular momentum as well?  That may eliminate that freedom.

Comment: Note in a gravitational potential, there isn't rotational symmetry and so the double pendulum doesn't conserve angular momentum.

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan : A *simple* pendulum passes through its lowest point repeatedly with various velocities.  You seem to be arguing that this never happens.  In a double pendulum, set the initial angles to $0$ (i.e., straight down).  You seem to claim that I have only one choice of initial angular velocities, which is absurd.

Comment: "A simple pendulum passes through its lowest point repeatedly with various velocities. You seem to be arguing that this never happens." Yes, I do indeed say it never happens.  That's a consequence of conservation of energy: at its lowest point all its energy is kinetic, so (1/2)mv^2 is the same every time it reaches the lowest point and thus the velocity is the same every time.

Comment: The magnitude is the same, the direction is not (plus\minus difference). Though for simple pendulum the motion is indeed periodic.

Comment: So is the answer yes or no ? By Poincarré theorem I would say yes but you seem to imply otherwise.

Comment: @agemO What case are you talking about? Single pendulum or double one?

Comment: The double one as in the original question

Comment: @agemO Well, in this case the phase space is 4D and the theorem doesn't hold. The theorem is only applicable for 2D phase spaces. The meaning of this is that there is no chaos for dynamic of phase space dimension less than 3.

Comment: I'm taking about https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poincar%C3%A9_recurrence_theorem
not
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poincar%C3%A9%E2%80%93Bendixson_theorem

Comment: @agemO Poincare recurrence theorem says nothing about periodic orbits. It states that the system will be arbitrary close to past states in later times. Not the same. And also it says nothing about the time it takes fot that to happen. Indeed, this seems to cause the confusion: the spatial trajectory of the mass intersects itself many times and it looks like the motion is periodic while it is actually not. Just very close to that.

Comment: Indeed it's not actually periodic. You should add a clear 'no' to your answer. It's not only a real space / phase space confusion, because applying the reasonning to phase space leads to Poncarré theorem which I think is close to what the op meant (i.e if you wait a long time there is clearly no other solution than passing close to the starting phase space point). It's also confusing regarding limits and infinity.

Comment: @agemO Thanks. I edited my answer as you suggested. Let me know if you think I should add something else.

Comment: Does "general trajectories of double pendulum are not periodic" mean "**all** trajectories of all double pendulums are not periodic" resp: "**no** trajectory of any double pendulum is periodic"? Or does it mean "**in general** trajectories of double pendulums are not periodic (but there are exceptions)"?

Comment: @HansStricker I meant your second interpretation. Indeed, there is for example a trajectory where both masses swing with the same angle vs. time. Nevertheless, note that this trajectory is not stable to small perturbations due to the chaotic nature of the system. It means that even slight imprecision in the initial conditions will lead to entirely different results. Thus, in the real world it would be nearly impossible to set such a motion.

Comment: And even in the simulated world (because of finite precision)? So one could never see such a motion? Or might it have a closed form, so you don't have to use Runge-Kutta?

Comment: What exactly do you mean with "the same angle vs. time"?

Comment: @HansStricker If you try to solve the general equation in the computer you are probably right. But you can avoid this by setting $\theta_1=\theta_2$ and solving for a single angle.

Comment: But what does it mean "setting $\theta_1 = \theta_2$"? Why should I do this? Why may I do this?

Comment: @HansStricker It means you confine yourself to the $\theta_1=\theta_2$ and $\dot{\theta}_1=\dot{\theta}_2$ part of the entire 4D phase space. If you can then find a solution that stays there, then it also exists in the whole phase space.

Answer (score 18):

From wikipedia, the [phase space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phase_space) of a dynamical system is defined as

> ... a space in which all possible states of a system are represented, with each possible state corresponding to one unique point in the phase space. For mechanical systems, the phase space usually consists of **all possible values of position and momentum variables**.

For the double pendulum there are two position variables $\theta_1, \theta_2$ and two momentum variables $\dot \theta_1, \dot \theta_2$. So the phase space is 4 dimensional. If the system returns to the same point in its phase space its motion will repeat, because the state of the system is identical with its previous state so its subsequent motion is identical.

The 2 dimensional space with axes $\theta_1, \theta_2$ is **not** the phase space for this system. It is only a projection or "shadow" of the phase space.

Each point on the 2D plane $(\theta_1, \theta_2)$ corresponds to an infinite number of points in the 4D phase space, each with a different combination of $(\dot \theta_1, \dot \theta_2)$. The system can return to the same position $(\theta_1, \theta_2)$ with a different combination of momenta $(\dot \theta_1, \dot \theta_2)$ each time. The trajectory in the 2D plane $(\theta_1, \theta_2)$ can pass through the same point an infinite number of times without retracing the same path, because each of these intersections corresponds to a different state of the system.

So it is possible for the double pendulum to never return to the same point in its 4D phase space and therefore its motion can be non-periodic.

Answer (score 6):

So your argument is not quite correct because of the existence of space-filling curves and fractals and the like; to take a simple example imagine a spiral over the whole plane $\mathbb R^2$, clearly not self-intersecting, and cut out the unit circle from it, then map it according to the Möbius transform $(x, y) \mapsto \left(\frac x{x^2 +y^2}, \frac y{x^2+y^2}\right).$ This transform maps the exterior of the unit circle into the circle, but it's totally invertible and cannot cause self-intersection. (It is also conformal and some other nice things that don't really matter here.) What you would get, if you look at this like a phase space, would be a harmonic oscillator with dissipation which never allows it to quite come to rest but always saps a tiny bit of energy from the thing. One could probably find that in the 4D phase space of a double pendulum there would be weird Hamiltonians which conserve energy and yet still do this. Trajectories need never be periodic precisely.

What you *can* prove is that for a gobsmackingly huge number of systems, the vast majority of the "nearby" paths to these exceptional ones will nonetheless return back to "nearby" whence they came, so that in general you will see a pattern of physics from $0 < t < \tau$ and then you will see an arbitrarily close copy of that from $T < t < T + \tau$ for some big $T$. This is known as the [Poincaré recurrence theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poincar%C3%A9_recurrence_theorem).

Comment: "So your argument is not quite correct because of the existence of space-filling curves and fractals and the like" Actually space-filling curves are always self-intersecting.

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan But in this case, the curve doesn't actually have to be space-filling. The spiral is a good example; it will never fully fill any area, but it will not self-intersect either. Instead the distance between consecutive revolutions just grows smaller and smaller.